# Javascript date issue on IE 7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, webmethod

i have a web method from which i am returning Date it is returning date like `"Mon Sep 30 07:26:14 EDT 2013"` now when i am converting formatt of date in my javascript code:

```
var d= SomeDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"); //Somedate is comming from web method
```

But in IE7`(09/30/2013 04:56:14 PM)` it is showing wrong Time but in IE9 `(09/30/2013 07:26:14 AM)`its working fine.

How can we do it in IE7?

Comment: Can you check if IE7 and IE9 agree on the timestamp? do `SomeDate.getTime()`, this should give you the same number.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.format` doesn't work on IE7.
You can use the Date class like this :

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var month = currentDate.getMonth();
var day = currentDate.getDay();
month = (month < 10) ? '0' + month : month;
day = (day < 10) ? '0' + day : day;
var formatedDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + currentDate.getFullYear() + " " + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();
alert (formatedDate);
```

Example : http://jsbin.com/enAqohO/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How can we convert this into 12 Hr clocks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is related to timezone. IE7 does not recognise the timezone 'EDT' in the string.

I will try moving the 'EDT' to the end of the string. Could you try

```
new Date("Mon Sep 30 07:26:14 2013 EDT")
```

and see if it give your the right result ?  Sorry, I don't have IE7 to test.

Comment: How can i move EDT to last in code , that data i am geting as a return from webMethod , i have to add seprate logic to move EDT in last